# anyone know how to rebrand ubuntu 23.04 with the budgie DE in cubic?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 23.04

I need help rebranding and changing the ubuntu name, and logo across the whole system on cubic, yet I can't seem to find the commands to rebrand everything. If anyone knows them, please send.